# How to run exported Parameters Variation experiment in a headless environment automatically?

Tags: anylogic

I would like to run an exported *Parameters Variation* experiment on my Linux machine. Although there is a way for setting a Simulation experiment to start automatically running the batch file (or .sh file for Linux) once the file is opened, I cannot find a similar option for Parameters Variation in which I am running 40 different replications of the same model. In Windows, you need to open the file and manually click the `Run` button for this.

Considering Linux OS, which is a headless environment, how can I make the model start automatically once I run the command `./mySimulationModel_linux.sh`?

Currently when I run this command, the model does nothing. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to make use of a custom experiment object that will run the parameter variation for you. You can then export the custom experiment and call the `customExperiment.sh` Have not tried it but it should work

Answer (score 0):

The best option would be to add some code to your "Initial Experiment setup:" section to get it to run without any user input

just add `run();`

[image]

Of course, you can add any of other code as well there.